# Getting process ID's

Tags: c++, winapi, process, tchar, dword

My program below will concatenate the names of the processes into the `names` string. How can I change it to include the process ID's instead of names? What type should `names` be, how to initialise it and how to concatenate every `proc32.th32ProcessID` in it ?

```
PROCESSENTRY32 proc32;    
TCHAR names[MAX_PATH]=L""; 

if(hSnap == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    cout<<"invalid handle value error!\n";
    return;
}


proc32.dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32);


if(!Process32First(hSnap, &proc32))
{
    cout<<"Tread32First() error!\n";
    CloseHandle(hSnap);
    return ;
}

do
{

        //cout<<"Current process id: "<<GetCurrentProcessId()<<"\n";
        wcout<<L"Process Name: "<<proc32.szExeFile<<"\n";
        cout<<"Process ID: "  <<proc32.th32ProcessID<<"\n";
        cout<<"Thread Count: "<<proc32.cntThreads<<"\n"<<endl;

            lstrcat(names, proc32.szExeFile);
            lstrcat(names, L"\n");



}while(Process32Next(hSnap, &proc32));
```

Comment: This is not C, it is C++. So use `std::string` or `std::wstring`.

Comment: To be more specific about what David meant: use a `std::basic_string<TCHAR>` for `names`, such that you can easily concatenate the strings and not worry about the array size.

Comment: seriously? Did you read the code, especially the part where it prints out the process id twice, and compares the process id with the current process id?

Comment: I do that to exclude the current id. It will be printed every time, actually but already excluded that part from my original program. Mind showing me an example @MicroVirus? I'm a bit confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using C++ anyway, you should make use of it.  Use `std::vector`, `std::wstring`, etc:

```
PROCESSENTRY32W proc32;    
vector<wstring> names; 
vector<DWORD> ids;

if (hSnap == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    cout << "invalid handle value error!" << endl;
    return;
}

proc32.dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32W);

if (!Process32FirstW(hSnap, &proc32))
{
    cout << "Tread32First() error!" << endl;
    CloseHandle(hSnap);
    return ;
}

do
{
    //cout << "Current process id: " << GetCurrentProcessId() << endl;
    wcout << L"Process Name: " << proc32.szExeFile << endl;
    cout << "Process ID: " << proc32.th32ProcessID << endl;
    cout << "Thread Count: " << proc32.cntThreads << endl << endl;

    names.push_back(proc32.szExeFile);
    ids.push_back(proc32.th32ProcessID);
}
while (Process32Next(hSnap, &proc32));

// use names and ids as needed...
```

Or:

```
PROCESSENTRY32W proc32;    
vector<PROCESSENTRY32W> procs; 

if (hSnap == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    cout << "invalid handle value error!" << endl;
    return;
}

proc32.dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32W);

if (!Process32FirstW(hSnap, &proc32))
{
    cout << "Tread32First() error!" << endl;
    CloseHandle(hSnap);
    return ;
}

do
{
    //cout << "Current process id: " << GetCurrentProcessId() << endl;
    wcout << L"Process Name: " << proc32.szExeFile << endl;
    cout << "Process ID: " << proc32.th32ProcessID << endl;
    cout << "Thread Count: " << proc32.cntThreads << endl << endl;

    procs.push_back(proc32);
}
while (Process32Next(hSnap, &proc32));

// use procs as needed...
```